# Find a form within an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe that loads a webpage that has a form. I would like to select this form without knowing its ID or name etc., however the following doesn't seem to work:

```
var aform = $('form');
var iframeform = $("#myiframe").contents().find(aform);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

`$('form');` will get any form in the main page, not inside any frame. You need to get inside the frame first

Try

```
var iframeform = $("#myiframe").contents().find('form');
```

Note that it will only work if iframe and page have same origin and also iframe has loaded when you look for the form